# Retrieving last modified file from piped find results

Tags: linux, bash, loops, find, pipe

I'm new to bash, so if I'm going about this the wrong way please let me know. Right now I'm trying to find all jars that start with R and end with .jar, i've achieved this like so

```
sudo find / -mount -name "R*.jar" | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

However I'm not sure how to use the piped data to grab the last modified file. I'll be running the last modified file with java

```
java -jar $lastFile -debug
```

but as I stated I have no idea how to go about seeing which was last modified. Since i'll be running it I've got to be able to access it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
java -jar `find / -type f -name "R*.jar" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k 1nr | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | head -n 1` -debug
```

A credit for [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified) for the `sort` command.